# Printing the expression result in hexadecimal format using visual studio's trace points

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, hex

Does anybody know, whether it's possible to output the values in a hexadecimal via the visual studio's trace points?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have recently found out, how this can be done. Visual studio provides a way to specify the format we want to see the expression in the watch/immediate windows. You can do the following:

```
foo, x
```

This will display the foo variable in the hexadecimal format regardless of whether the hex or dec displayed is globally enabled in VS. You can also specify lots of other display formats. The full list can be found there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx.

This feature also works with trace points, which is very useful when you want the values to appear in hexadecimal format in output window.

```
{bar,x}
```

Comment: Does not appear that {bar,x} works as TracePoint syntax when debugging a WEC2013 / Compact Framework program.